# Cannot access referenced project constants

Tags: vb.net, project-reference, access-levels

I'm having an issue using a module across multiple project in the same solution (a regular project and a test project for unit tests).  I'm trying to follow the example code from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182532(v=vs.110).aspx (but using VB.NET instead of C#).

So I've got 2 projects, ZBank and ZBankTests.  ZBankTests has a reference to ZBank.  ZBank has a class, clsAccount (namespace BankAccount) and a module, modConstants (namespace BankConstants).  clsAccount imports ZBank.BankConstants and can use its constant variables.

ZBankTests has a class, clsAccountTests (namespace ZBank.BankAccount.Tests) that imports ZBank.BankAccount and ZBank.BankConstants.  I can use the BankAccount class fine, but it errors:

```
"'DebitAmountExceedsBalanceMessage' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level."
```

I've also compiled the module into a DLL, but after adding the reference to it, neither project can import it or use its variables (tried after reading this: [Using the same modules in multiple projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4560261/using-the-same-modules-in-multiple-projects)).

Code for the module:

```
Namespace BankConstants

    Module modConstants

        Public DebitAmountExceedsBalanceMessage As String = "Debit amount exceeds balance"
        Public DebitAmountLessThanZeroMessage As String = "Debit amount less than zero"

    End Module

End Namespace
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Module` access level is `Friend` by default. You have to explicitly declare it as `Public` if you want to use it from outside the project boundaries.

```
Public Module modConstants
    ' your constants
End Module
```

See [`Module` statement documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aaxss7da.aspx) for more information.

Comment: So simple.  Thanks, Crono.